# Why nodejs test case with nodeunit keep loading in webstorm after successfully passed the test cases?

Tags: node.js, testing, server-side, webstorm, nodeunit

I am working on nodejs project. And I am using `nodeunit` npm module to test my server-side codebase. I am using [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) as an editor for writing my codes and also testing the server-side code with the help of nodeunit module.

Everything is working perfectly, my test cases passed correctly but the test cases progress is keep loading in Webstorm status panel. I have manually to stop that each time. Does anybody have any idea on this?

Comment: Could you please specify what "test cases progress is keep loading" phrase means.
Is "Stop" button active (i.e. a Node.js process that runs tests is alive)?

Comment: When you run a test in webstorm with nodeunit configuration then it will open a status panel in webstorm IDE to show the on going status. So there the process is keep loading after successfully passed the test cases.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Yes, sure, WebStorm shows a status panel when a test in webstorm with nodeunit configuration is run.
What I'd like to know is the place in UI that shows that the process is keep loading.
Anyway it's a bug and it'd be much appreciated if you would file an issue in the http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB#newissue=yes . It'd be more convenient to discuss the bug there. For example, it's possible to attach a screenshot there.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I have this only when debugging, not with normal run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling done() at the end?  For example

```
exports.globalSetterTest = function(test){
    var app = require('../helpers/globalsetter');
    app.setData("abc");
    var res = app.getData();
    test.equal(res, "abc", "msg");
    test.done();
};
```

I have the same setup as you and here are some sample tests I wrote.
https://github.com/captainchung/webstormNodeUnitTests/blob/master/test/spec.js

Comment: OK. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: all `nodeunit` tests pass, but Webstorm's spinner keeps going forever. I solved it by explicitly closing the database connection that was opened by the code under test -- something I didn't have to do outside test code because my database driver prefers to keep the connections alive in a connection pool.